# Apache rewrite for SEFs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to have requests to be handled by index.php

For instance

If I type SEFs in the browser

```
http://localhost/friends
http://localhost/me
```

Rewrites to

```
http://localhost/index.php/friends
http://localhost/index.php/me
```

So I could access friends or me from $_REQUEST['PATH_lNFO']

I've mod rewrite on and allow all directive set for the root directory in apache.

Need a .htaccess file,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look in this article   http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/    for this RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)$ display.php?country=$1&state=$2&city=$3 [L]

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rtest
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mathpdq\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mathpdq.com/rtest/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

http://mathpdq.com/rtest/fred

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^friends$ index.php/friends [L]
RewriteRule ^me$ index.php/me [L]
```

that's all.

`$_REQUEST['PATH_INFO']` will be set to "`/friends`" or "`/me`".

(Depending on your server configuration `ORIG_PATH_INFO` might have to be used instead of `PATH_INFO`)